# Durett's proof of Skorokhod’s representation theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, brownian-motion

I have a question on Skorokhod’s representation theorem in Durrett's *Probability: Theory and Examples* ( https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTEv5a.pdf  starting at page 347). It says below:

[part 1 of proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7adHB.jpg)

[part 2 of proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oI340.jpg)

I don't understand the circled equation (part 2 of proof). It looks like the expectation is taken over $(-\infty,0) \times (0,\infty)$, with probability measure defined in (8.1.1). But the function whose expectation is taken depends on measures induced by points in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
What kind of technique is this? Can anyone give me a rigorous (non-intuitive) justification? Any reference is appreciated!